# Factory reset from recovery mode not working on Samsung Galaxy GT-S5830i

Tags: factory-reset

I previously asked a question about my phone having a few issues with force stopping and I have tried to factory reset it from recovery mode lots of times but it just stays the same.

Comment: So, what is not working? The factory reset process or the issues not being solved?

Comment: It will not factory reset.

Comment: But becuase it does not hard reset it does not resolve the problems.

Comment: plz answer this question i have a really important phone number on there and i cant get it off because i have a chromebook!

Comment: huh... what is happening when you boot to recovery? Can you see the option for resetting? Or you are unable to boot into recovery? Remember, you'll lose  everything stored in the phone.

Comment: I am aware that I will lose everything in storege but I have the only thing I really need off of it; I am just trying to prevent having to buy a new one. Everything seems to work fine apart from when you boot it up it is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Hum... I think your file system has somehow turned out to be read-only that can explain everything returning back to previous settings. This happens when the memory chip is damaged